# Python, Flask - Ошибка 500 после редиректа

Tags: python, flask

Написан на python код с помощью которого можно войти, выйти и попасть на главную страницу в системе linux

```
 @app.route('/')
def index():
    if 'username' in session:
        return 'Logged in as %s' % escape(session['username'])
    return 'You are not logged in'

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        if authenticate(str(username), str(password)):
            session['username'] = request.form['username']
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
        else:
            return 'Invalid username/password'
    return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    # remove the username from the session if it's there
    session.pop('username', None)
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Далее также есть файлы `login.html, index.html и layout.html`

login.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
{% if error %}<p class="error"><strong>Error:</strong> {{ error }}{% endif %}
<form action="{{ url_for('login') }}" method="post">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="rpi-logo">
            <img src="static/images/Raspi-PGB001.png">
        </div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="username" required>
        <div class="bar">
            <i></i>
        </div>
        <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="password" required>
        <button>Sign in</button>
    </div>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

layout.html

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Web APi</title>
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
    <div class=page>
{% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
    <div class=flash>{{ message }}</div>
{% endfor %}
{% block body %}{% endblock %}
</div>
```

index.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
        <div>INDEX.HTML</div>
        {% if error %}<p class="error"><strong>Error:</strong> {{ error }}{% endif %}
        <form action="{{ url_for('preview') }}" method="post">
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="rpi-logo">
                    <img src="static/images/Raspi-PGB001.png">
                        </div>
                <button>Start Preview</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        {% endblock %}
```

В данный момент работает следующие - я могу зайти в линукс, после нажатия на кнопку `Sign In,` вылетает ошибка `500`. Никак не могу понять, где я напортачил.

Comment: А само сообщение об ошибке привести можешь?

Comment: @MichaelPak Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Comment: @MichaelPak как я понял связана она с `return redirect(url_for('index'))`

Comment: `DEBUG = True` в конфиг приложения (или просто `app.debug = True` без конфига) и нормальный текст ошибки сюда

Comment: И код функции `authenticate` тоже не помешает

Comment: @andreymal DEBUG = True у меня вставлен, но ничего не где я не вижу. Вся authenticate состоит из - `from simplepam import authenticate`

Comment: При DEBUG = True фласк не может писать столь скудные ошибки, перепроверяйте

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36468/discussion-between-insider-and-andreymal).

Comment: @andreymal я создал чат, давайте перейдем туда

Comment: @andreymal оказывается debugger не работает через удаленку, а сказать мне об этом никто не может

Comment: Работает, каждый день flask-приложение черед удаленку тыкаю и каждый же день с дебаггером сталкиваюсь